# ng serve localhost:4200 when opened it downloads an empty file

Tags: angular

when I ng serve my Angular project and then open localhost:4200, there is no redirection, instead it is just downloading a file called 'download' whose file type is 'file'.

I dont really get what's happening. Yesterday everything worked well! Didnt update anything, just commited changes. Checking out old changes or other branches (via git) wont solve the problem.

Edit:
There is a warning in the console:
 `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/x-httpd-php: "http://localhost:4200/".`

And there's only one request in the network tab:

```
General
Request URL: http://localhost:4200/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:4200
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2399
Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 13 Jun 2019 13:25:04 GMT
ETag: W/"95f-OzUIvH6AGkYTzrBRrWDtbW34jgE"
X-Powered-By: Express

Request Headers
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: io=jtCE1d_N_SpFiMybAAAA
Host: localhost:4200
Pragma: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
```

Deleted and cloned it again

Also tried to running another port `ng serve --port 8080` and same thing happening

Running another project with ng serve is possible (also port 4200)

**Update**:

**Solved** this by reinstalling node, git and global @angular/cli. Then cloned project again from its repository to another directory and ng serve works now!

**Edit Solve**: Just opened VSC and tried ng serve and its back! Is this a prob with VSC?

Comment: That sounds so strange. Could you open your developer tools, go the the network tab, then reload, and see what network requests are being made? 

Also is there anything in the console?

Comment: Anything else running on port 4200 on your machine?

Comment: Can you show all of the resopnse headers for that one request?